# How to add different affiliate codes to different labels of the blog in Blogger?

Tags: blogger

Using conditional Tag in Blogger!

`<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>...content...</b:if>`

Just like that how to set different advertisements codes to the different Label Page in the blogger?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == "LabelName"'>...content...</b:if>
```